# Backup slides with `beammerappendixnote` and `\pause` breaks hyperlinks

Tags: beamer, appendix, href

I'm using `\pause`-steps, and [`beamerappendixnote`](https://github.com/csemken/beamerappendixnote) to provide links to appendix slides. The appendix slide gets linked after the first `\pause`:

```
\documentclass[20pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerappendixnote}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Main title}
        Main \pause content \pause \vfill
        \appxnote{Appendix note}{Note content}
    \end{frame}
    \printappxnotes
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this generates a new (identical) appendix for every frame on the main slide.

[image: screenshot]

A quick workaround is adding `\only<\value{beamerpauses}>{...}` around the appxnote, but this, unfortunately, breaks the hyperlinks, so navigating is not possible anymore.

Desired behavior:

- Each appendix slide to be generated only once
- Hyperlinks to work for navigation

Comment: Same question posted on github: https://github.com/csemken/beamerappendixnote/issues/2

Comment: something like `\only<\value{beamerpauses}>{\label<\value{beamerpauses}>{ban-back-1}\appxnote{Appendix note}{Note content}}` could work.

Comment: True, but this would only work if I have a single slide with an appendix/backup, no? Otherwise, I'd have to manually figure out which tables to set (ban-back-X), or am i missing something?

Comment: the style uses `\seq_count:N \g_ban_titles`,  if you set the label before the note, you probably need somethings like `\ExplSyntaxOn\newcommand\currentnote{\inteval{\seq_count:N \g_ban_titles + 1}}\ExplSyntaxOff`  and then you can use {ban-back-\currentnote}` (all untested).

Comment: This is crazy because this just works out of the box. Amazing. Thank you! I'll test it some more and let you know if I come across any problems.